# Gracefully extend AD attribute pwdLastSet via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Over a period of 35 days, we will be forcing users to reset their passwords at next login.

I've tested setting a users pwdLastSet attribute to 0 then -1, effectively resetting it to that point in time, so they'd be required to reset their password 90 days out (our current policy for password age is 90 days).

What I'm trying to figure out is how to gracefully change the pwdLastSet date for my users so that I "decompress" their password age from 35 days back to 90 days (we get a lot of password related calls every day, doing nothing would only make things worse).

I am capturing the users with these commands:

```
$dateam = (Get-Date $date -hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).ToFileTime()
$datepm = (Get-Date $date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).ToFileTime()
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter {(pwdLastSet -gt $dateam) -and (pwdLastSet -lt $datepm) -and (extensionAttribute2 -notlike "*")} -Properties pwdLastSet, extensionAttribute2 -SearchBase "OU=users,DC=domain,DC=com").SamAccountName
```

Because I can only set the pwdLastSet attribute date to the current day/time, I believe I need to run something daily to capture users, save the usernames to a file to be picked up in the future (and then setting extensionAttribute2 to any value so they don't get picked up again in a future run)

Where I'm struggling is the logic in keeping things to 90 days. If possible, I want to prevent a user from having their pwdLastSet attribute set, say 35 days after their forced password change, so in effect their next password change is 105 days out.

I have all sorts of test code, but nothing terribly useful. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I get what you're trying to do. Sorry, I miss read. So, users that have let say 35 days left before they need to change their passwords will get another 90  days. So you'll want to do your time like this:

```
$dateam = ((Get-Date -hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).Add("-55")).ToFileTime()
$datepm = ((Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).Add("-90")).ToFileTime()
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter {(pwdLastSet -gt $dateam) -or (pwdLastSet -lt $datepm) -and (extensionAttribute2 -notlike "*")} -Properties pwdLastSet, extensionAttribute2)
```

This gets all the users with a password that has 35 days left.

```
$dateam = ((Get-Date -hour 0 -Minute 00 -Second 00).Add("-55")).ToFileTime()
$datepm = ((Get-Date -Hour 23 -Minute 59 -Second 59).Add("-90")).ToFileTime()
$users = (Get-ADUser -Filter {(pwdLastSet -gt $dateam) -or (pwdLastSet -lt $datepm) -and (extensionAttribute2 -notlike "*")} -Properties  pwdLastSet, extensionAttribute2)

foreach($user in $users)
{
    $user.pwdLastSet = 0
    $user.PasswordNeverExpires = $false
    Set-ADUser -Instance $user

    $user.pwdLastSet = -1
    Set-ADUser -Instance $user
}
```

Comment: I just double checked my work against my test enviroment and if you want 35 days left on a 90 day policy, you need to subtract 35 from 90 giving you 55. So you'd have a -55 for the days.